# Unable to start AVD on Windows 10

Tags: android, mobile, android-virtual-device, hardware-acceleration, haxm

I have Android Studio 1.5.1 running on Windows 10.
I´m trying to run an AVD but it throws the following error:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

So I tried to install HAXM but when I launch the installer got the error:

```
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). 
HAXM cannot be installed.
```

I already check on my Windows Features and Hyper-V is not enabled.

Please address me what should I do in order to run AVD.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Intel Virtualization (VT) is enabled in your BIOS. 
Also ensure whether your antivirus isnt blocking installation of haxm.